# Heroku deploy docker image via CircleCi 401 error

Tags: docker, github, heroku, circleci, cicd

I`m using CircleCi, GitHub, Docker to deploy app to Heroku, but after Heroku security issues, I had to revoke the connection to GitHub, and after reconnection the github repo I got this error while attempting to run docker login:

> Error response from daemon: login attempt to
> https://registry.heroku.com/v2/ failed with status: 401 Unauthorized

Login command:

```
`docker login -u "_" -p "shell heroku auth:token" registry.heroku.com`
```

Answer (score 0):

Longterm API key generation is a workaround for this issue

```
heroku authorizations:create
```

Probably temporary token throws the error due to recent Heroku security problems: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2413